# Constructing python-click commands

Tags: python, python-click

I have a command like :

`$trial login --user`

For this I used `python-click` to wrap my python functions and is working fine. I am very new to `python-click` and having having to construct a command in a certain way than what is mentioned above.

Below is my present code of a file `trial.py`,

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--user', prompt='Username', help='Username.')
@click.option('--password', prompt='Password', help='Password.')
def login(user, password):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    login_cli(user,password)
    print "done"

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass
```

And my `setup.py` file looks like the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='trial',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['trial'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        trial=trial:cli
    ''',
)
```

But now I want to change the command a little. I want to make it something like,

```
$trial k8s login --user
```

I want to add a series of k8s commands but don't know how to include it in the code and would want some guidance on the same.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to make another `group` that's a child of `cli`, so make a `k8s` function and decorate it with `cli.group()`, then change `login` to be a `k8s.command()`